# ModuleNotFoundError when using PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

When running a script with this configuration in PyCharm:

[image: Pycharm run configurations]

I get

```
/home/name/anaconda3/envs/butterfly/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for '/home/name/PycharmProjects/butterflydetector/butterflydetector/train.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '/home/name/PycharmProjects/butterflydetector/butterflydetector/train')
```

while it works when I run the following command from the terminal (same conda environment activated and at location ~/PycharmProjects/butterflydetector):

```
python3 -m butterflydetector.train --arguments
```

What's the difference between the two ways of running this script and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually easy, what *exactly* the problem is I still can't say. To just get it running clear the interpreter options line in the above image (or at least get rid of the `-m`) and click on where it says 'Script path:'. Chose 'Module name:' instead and there you go. Also change the path to the script from the absolute path like it is in the above image to, in that specific case, `butterflydetector.train`.